# What is this connection of resistors? Parallel or serial?

Tags: resistors, serial, parallel

How i can simplify this electric circuit?

[image]

Comment: Parallel is when the resistors are connected between the same two nodes. Series is when all current through one resistor must go through the other. Which one do you see here?

Comment: Definitely serial. I was mistaken for a parallel connection. I got thinking that the parallel connection is only if the ends of resistance are to the same potentials.

Comment: Simplification: E in series with a resistance of value R1||R2. No further simplification.

Comment: umm... not R1||R2 . The two E cancel out providing net 0V with R1+R2

Comment: This shows a series loop that would cause the voltage sources to oppose eachother, so once their voltages balanced, no current should flow between them, but in this context they are in series to eachother and the two resistors can be combined by addition.  However, if you've shown the voltage sources as intended, and they are cells, the left and right ends of the diagram would be connection points from which this model of parallel batteries with internal resistance fed a load.  Context would determine which was intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The schematic is something looking like two voltage sources connected in parallel.

Two identical voltage source with internal resistance, I theory we can consider every identical voltage source will have same internal resistance. but its not.. it will vary.

With my understanding it is an voltage sources in parallel configuration with their internal resistance.

Comment: It definitely does look like one, though it is missing the leads from between the resistances (positive) and between the supplies (negative) to assume so. I would guess its just a diagram of one without a load attached to it, for simplicities sake

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Ideal situation:

Resistors are in series. Both end nodes of the resistors have a potential of E volts, therefore, the potential across both resistors are 0V. This results in zero amps current.

Non-ideal situation:

Both batteries have slightly different voltage source value with its own internal resistances. This will incur a different voltage potential at both end notes, resulting in a potential difference across both resistors. This will cause a low amount of current to conduct through the resistors.

Answer (score 1):

The two resistors are in series (so they add), and the two voltage sources are back to back (so they minus [voltage drop]). The corresponding circuit would be like so:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDQxn2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The battery is at 0 V because the E Volt batteries are back to back, cancelling out the voltages as they are the same potential.